# how to bind datagridview to database at page load time in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, datagridview

I use below code in try catch block but it gives exception"**'table' argument cannot be null. Parameter name: table**" .My table name is caste and that table two columns are there srno and castename .But it say that my table has no data.Memory table is a datatable.

```
 Dim Dset As New DataSet()
            Dset = New DataSet()
            Dset.Tables.Add(MemoryTable)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = Dset.Tables("caste")
```

I tried data connect with database with using datasource but it gives service pack 1 error
'One is to use data binding on your TextBox controls and assigning the same DataSource.but its gives error

Comment: there was no Try/Catch in **VB6**; for VB.NET there is a lot missing or wrong in your code.  Everything there is null, no data in the dataset; what is  `MemoryTable`? and no datatable named "caste" created or filled.  [Here is a good example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset(v=vs.110).aspx) of how to use these things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show the definition of `MemoryTable`, but you do say it's a data table.  If it's an object of type `System.Data.DataTable`, then it will have a property called `TableName`.

When you access a `DataTable` in a `DataSet` with a string index value, the value you are passing is the table's `TableName` property.  So `Dset.Tables("caste")` is looking for a `DataTable` whose `TableName` property is set to "caste".  If it can't find one, it will return `Null`.  That looks like what's happening.

So set `MemoryTable.TableName` to "caste" and the error may go away.

I assume that `MemoryTable` actually has rows in it?  If not, that may be a reason why you're getting the message about your table having no data.

So your code should look something like this:

```
Dim Dset As New DataSet()  ' You don't have to do a separate assignment to Dset
                           ' if you use New in the declaration, so we can omit that line.'
MemoryTable.TableName = "caste"
Dset.Tables.Add(MemoryTable)
DataGridView1.DataSource = Dset.Tables("caste")
```

And, actually, you can use `MemoryTable` as your data source without having to add it to a `DataSet`, unless you need to for some other reason.

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = MemoryTable
```

I hope this helps.